# Why I can't mix javascript functions with jquery methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to using jQuery(I'm good with regular js), and I'm having a hard time, really really hard time, trying to figure out this, I've been reading for days, because I usually find the answer on my own, but this has gone too far.

I wan't to know, why, when coded like this:

```
$(document).ready(slideShow());

function slideShow() {
    alert("enters");
    $('ul.imgslider').each(function () {
        $('li', this).css("display", "block");
        $('li', this).fadeOut(1000);
    });
};
```

The alert is executed, but the .each() is not. If you code it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function slideShow() {
    alert("enters");
    $('ul.imgslider').each(function () {
        $('li', this).css("display", "block");
        $('li', this).fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

Everything executes. I just don't get it and I wonder why that happens? And even more strangely, in jsfiddle it does get executed, but it doesn't when I run it locally. I'm using jquery-2.0.3.min.js.

Comment: What is your HTML? I feel that there's only one `ul.imgslider`, which doesn't need an `each()` function!

Comment: In your top example, you are executing slideShow immediately before passing it to ready(). Try "ready(slideShow)" without the parenthesis that are currently making it a function call.

Comment: or it just doesn't exist before the document is ready.

Comment: You need to understand how anonymous functions work, and what it means to pass a function as a parameter.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Even if there is more than one, he still doesn't need an `each()`.

Comment: There is only one ul.imgslider, what I'm intending to do is to iterate through the list, but as I wasn't able to get into the .each(), I couldn't move forward for debug. Tried "ready(slideShow)" and that worked, now I gotta figure out how to iterate through the list :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `$(document).ready(slideShow())` calls `slideShow` *immediately*, and passes *its return value* to the `ready` function.

```
$(slideShow);
```

That's how it should be done ;)

Comment: Sorry I can't mark this as the answer but this did work, I've spent so many hours trying to figure it out, dear god, thanks a lot.